# sed and PHP tags

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have a problem using SED.

I have a php file whit this structure in the very first line:

```
<?php echo 'first' ?><?php echo 'second' ?><?php echo 'third';?>
```

I'm trying to remove the first two statements and have as a result:

```
<?php echo 'third';?>
```

I've tried this code:

```
sed -i 's/<?php.*?>//
```

and this:

```
sed -i 's/<?php.*?><?php.*?>//
```

but both deletes the whole line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.*` is greedy: it matches all possible characters. This way, even `sed 's/<?php.*//' file` will also delete all the content in your file.

To prevent this greediness of `.*`, say "everything but a `?`" -> `[^?]*`:

```
sed 's/<?php[^?]*?><?php[^?]*?>//' file
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
<?php echo 'first' ?><?php echo 'second' ?><?php echo 'third';?>
$ sed 's/<?php[^?]*?><?php[^?]*?>//' file
<?php echo 'third';?>
```

Comment: also `?` will be considered as optional character in `<?php`

Comment: @Robert not in the default `sed`. To behave like this you have to either escape the ? or use `sed -r` for extended regex. See an example with `echo "hello" | sed 's/ei?//'` and `echo "hello" | sed -r 's/ei?//'`. The second one does replace `e` because `i` is optional. But in the first, nothing happens because it is looking for a plain `?`.

Comment: @fedorqui it works but now i have serious doubts on how sed apply pattern matching to strings... could you suggest me some useful resource on this topic?

Comment: @bicccio The sed manual covers it quite well: http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html See also my comment to Robert about the extended `sed` and normal one.